# what is '???' in Scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm learning `Scala` using `IntelliJ` IDE.

When I subs class `Element` and override `contents` method, IDE provided default implementation for `contents` method with definition `???`

Below code from the book `Programming in Scala, 3rd edition`

Element

```
abstract class Element {
  def contents: Array[String]

  def height = contents.length

  def width = if (height == 0) 0 else contents(0).length
}
```

ArrayElement

```
class ArrayElement(cont: Array[String]) extends Element {
  override def contents: Array[String] = ??? // impl provided by IDE
}
```

I don't see any issues in running the program but when I access the method I get below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
    at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:284)
    at org.saravana.scala.ArrayElement.contents(ScalaTest.scala:65)
```

Can someone explain what is `???` and use of it?

Comment: It's just a way to code not implement yet. and like the error says it's not implemented yet

Comment: it's basically a temporary value for non-implemented methods. Useful because it gets the IDE to shut up about it, and stop highlighting it as an error while you work on something else.

Comment: Just a general beginner's advice: Scala allows non-alphanumeric characters for method names, which means you're often confronted with something like `???` or `::` that looks like an operator (i.e., part of the language), when it's actually just a method. Just like with any method, can just use your IDE to look up the definition of such "pseudo-operators" (e.g., CTRL + b in IntelliJ).

Comment: sure, will check, thanks all!

Comment: The docs are your friend. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#???:Nothing

Comment: Could you please explain, what *exactly* is unclear in the documentation of the `???` method? That way, the Scala developers can improve the documentation, so that nobody ever has to ask that question again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`???` is designed as a placeholder and is a method defined in `Predef` (which is automatically imported by default)

It's definition is

`def ??? : Nothing = throw new NotImplementedError`

So it has return type `Nothing` and all it does is throw `NotImplementedError`.  This definition allows it to used as a placeholder implementation for methods you defined but haven't implemented yet but still want to be able to compile your program.

`Nothing` is a subtype of every type, which makes `???` a valid implementation no matter what type is expected.