# Scala dataframe Add new column based on other columns?

Tags: scala, dataframe

Sample DF:

```
A      B        C        D        E      F
3      6       26        0        7      2
1      14       3        21       9      1
```

What I want

```
A      B         C         D       E      F     G
3      6        26         0       7      2     14
1      14        3         21      9      1     9
```

I want the new column (G) to be (E * F). Anyone know how to do that cause after that i'll need to show only the biggest 20 numbers in the new G column

Sorry if this has been asked before and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{ col, desc}

val df: DataFrame = ???
df.withColumn("G", col("E") * col("F")).sort(desc("G")).show(20)
```

Comment: Are the question marks for the location of the dataframe? So lets say the dataframe is in "c:\data". The line would be val df: DataFrame = c:\data?

Comment: No, is just an example of a defined dataframe. The ??? characters is a way of creating incomplete code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717583/what-is-in-scala. You need to create your own dataframe reading from a file, for example.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. Another question. For column G. Lets say column B are names of people. Is it possible to get an output of column B names (only), based on the desc order of column G's values? So if the highest value of column G is 14 and that name is with Bob in column B, is it possible to only output just "Bob". and so on? Sorry if that isnt explained well lol but I'm not sure if I can code that

Comment: Yes, take a look to the when function: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-case-when-otherwise-example/ . Maybe it can help.

Answer (score 1):

With some shortcuts:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
val df = Seq(ABCDEF(3, 6, 26, 0, 7, 2), ABCDEF(1, 14, 3, 21, 9, 1)).toDF

df.show
/*
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|  F|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  3|  6| 26|  0|  7|  2|
|  1| 14|  3| 21|  9|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
*/

df.withColumn("G", 'E * 'F).sort(-'G).show
/*
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|  F|  G|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  3|  6| 26|  0|  7|  2| 14|
|  1| 14|  3| 21|  9|  1|  9|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
*/
```